# How would I go about converting these equations to C code?

Tags: c, trigonometry

I have these two equations

[image]
[image]

and I need to convert them to C code where you input`k` and `x`. The thing is I don't get that advanced levels of math, neither did I learn C in the past :D

Can anyone show me step by step what built-in functions can be used for this and how exactly should the logic behind the app work?

Cheers!

Comment: We are not a code writing/translation service. YOU write the code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: The math library will be of help to you. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/math_h.htm

Comment: The only function you need to use is `sin()`. Everything else is just multiplication and division.

Comment: And parentheses for grouping things.

Comment: And some iteration.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it.

Comment: `k` doesn't seem to be used in any of the formulas on the right side. So why would it need to be input?

Comment: Start by getting the equations right. Should be `k=1` to `n`. As is, the equations make no sense.

Comment: It looks like the inputs should be `n` and `x`, not `k` and `x`.

Comment: @Barmar `k` isn't used on the right, but isn't it supposed to create a sum of the values from `for(n=1; n<=k; n++);`?

Comment: And the formulas on the right are identical in both cases. This is just demonstrating a known relationship between `sin` and `cosine`. Look at graphs of the equations and you'll see they're the same except that they're offset from each other.

Comment: Since it's not used on the right, that means the result of the sum is independent of the value of `k`. But the real problem is what @user3386109 pointed out: you swapped the iteration and limit variables.

Comment: @Barmar `k` does not appear on the right because the `Σ` symbol means you sum the value of the expression for all values of `1 ≤ n ≤ k`. An earlier comment said "Should be `k=1 to n`" which is incorrect. It should be `n=1 to k`.

Comment: That can't be right. If `n` is the iteration variable, how can it be used on the right side, since it's not an input. And if `k` doesn't appear on the right side, it means the value of the equation doesn't depend on how many terms you're summing.

Comment: And why is it `Cos[kx]` instead of `Cos[nx]` on the left side, if `n` is the iteration variable?

Comment: @Barmar becaue `n` and `x` both appear on the right side. `k` is the limit of the iteration loop.

Comment: But the right side has to be calculated independently of the left side, and `n` comes from the summation on the left.

Comment: @Barmar feel free to write an answer.

Comment: It seems like you don't understand how equations work. This whole thing says that calculating the sum on the left is the same as calculating the formula on the right. Both sides have to take the same inputs.

Comment: I can't write an answer if the question is based on the wrong formula. Do you have a citation for the formula?

Comment: @Barmar the formula on the left, is the required solution, implemented by the expression on the right.

Comment: If you get the formula right, converting it to a programming language should be trivial. It's just arithmetic and the `sin()` function.

Comment: Do you have a citation for the formulas? It looks similar to https://www.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/202F09/sum-sin_kx.pdf

Comment: Actually, it looks identical to http://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/08/06/prove-a-formula-for-the-sum-from-k1-to-n-of-sin-kx/ except it has `k = 1 to n`, as suggested above.

Comment: It's not my equation. I just copied what the dude wanted me to convert.

Comment: As I mentioned, I haven't even learned that yet so yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is wrong. As shown [here](http://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/08/06/prove-a-formula-for-the-sum-from-k1-to-n-of-sin-kx/) (along with the proof of the derivation) the correct formula is

[image]

You have `k` and `n` swapped in your summation. The inputs should then be `x` and `n`. The correct code is then:

```
#include <math.h>
double sum_of_sin(double x, int n) {
    if (sin(x/2) == 0.0) {
        return 0.0; //prevent division by 0 for x multiple of 2π
    }
    return sin(n*x/2) * sin((n+1)*x/2) / sin(x/2);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I agree the formula was misquoted. I implemented the original: failed. Yours works.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out and for showing the code example. Now it makes more sense. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You can include the file math.h which has inbuilt functions like cos() and sin().
For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main ()
{
    double res;
    ret = cos(45);
    printf("The cos of angle 45 is %f",res);
    return 0;
 }
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Is that 45 radians?

Answer (score 0):

You have an equation that consists of two formulae. It is easy to write the two parts out, but it can be hard to find a solution. The right-hand part of the first formula would be:

```
float RHvalue;
RHvalue = (sin( ((n+1.0)*x) / 2.0 ) * sin(n * x/2.0) ) / sin(x/2.0);
```

now, what the values of `kx` would be, is another matter, though it would be easy to sum them.